# How can I dump a Sonarqube Database using pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, docker, sonarqube, pg-dump, postgresql-12

I want to get a sql dump of Sonarqube, the database is postgresql.

I execute the following command:

```bash
pg_dump -U postgres -h $HOST -p $PORT -d sonar -f sonar.sql
```

`pg_dump` version: ***pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 12.15***

All this instances are running on Kubernetes :

- Postgres Database server image: ***postgres:12.1-alpine***
- Sonarqube image: ***sonarqube:8.9.7-community***

I try to dump the database using `pg_dump`, but I always get the same error :

```
pg_dump: error: Dumping the contents of table "file_sources" failed: PQgetCopyData() failed.
pg_dump: error: Error message from server: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
pg_dump: error: The command was: COPY public.file_sources (project_uuid, file_uuid, line_hashes, line_hashes_version, data_hash, src_hash, revision, line_count, binary_data, created_at, updated_at, uuid) TO stdout;
```

I expect to dump the database succeffuly.